# How do I download the screenshots attached in the mail body

Tags: jakarta-mail

My program picks up mail from a PoP3 enabled email exchange server.
This mails have screen shots as part of the body.
I want to save the screenshots in the mail on the local drive.
I am using JavaMail API.
The API doesnot pick up the screenshot as an inline attachment but rather says the mime type of the email message is text/html.
How do I pick up this screenshot using javamail.
All I get is a src:cid

Answer (score 0):

If it's referencing the screenshots using src:cid, the text/html will be one part of a multipart/related and the screenshots will be other parts.  You can match up the cid reference with the Content-ID of the parts.

Comment: I have tried doing that without success! The cid reference does not match with the content-ID of the parts after I run a loop.

Comment: What cid references are you seeing and what Content-ID headers are you seeing?